# Measure, Integration & Real Analysis Sheldon Axler SEction 2B Exercise 12

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

the question can be found here, but is also repeated below.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function.

(a) For $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, let

$$G_k = \{a\in\mathbb{R}: \exists\delta>0 \text{ s.t. } \lvert f(b) - f(c)\rvert < \frac{1}{k}, \forall b,c\in(a-\delta, a+\delta\}.$$

Prove that $G_k$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

(b) Prove the set of points where $f$ is continuous equals $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}G_{k}$.

(c) Conclude that the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a Borel set.

So, I'm really just looking for a help at where to start. I think that  I have an idea of where to set for (b) since the definition of $G_k$ is essentially just the definition of continuity using $\varepsilon_k = \frac{1}{k}$, but I'm fairly lost on what to do for the other sections.

Thank you!

Comment: The book mentioned in this question was published in Springer's Open Access program. The electronic version of the book is legally available for free at https://measure.axler.net/ or on the Springer website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

For (a), what happens if we wiggle $a$ a little bit? That is, we know that $a \in G_k$ satisfies some property. Can you show that actually some open set around $a$ is *also* in $G_k$? Do you see why that would show that $G_k$ is open?

As for showing it, we know that if we stay within $\delta$ of $a$, something good happens. Can you show that for every point within $\delta/2$ of $a$ (say), there's a smaller radius around those points for which good things keep happening?

For (b), you're completely right!

For (c), you've shown the points of continuity is a (countable!) intersection of open sets $G_k$. Why must this be borel?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: That helps a lot!

Comment: 0
Down vote
could you explain more why Gk is open ? Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: @M.L.M -- Say $a \in G_k$. So $|f(b) - f(c)| < \frac{1}{k}$ whenever $b,c$ are within $\delta$ of $a$. Now can you find an $\epsilon$ so that every $a'$ within $\epsilon$ of $a$ _also_ satisfies this property (possibly for a different $\delta$)? As a hint, if you pick $a'$ close enough to $a$, can you make it so that everything "close" to $a'$ is _also_ close to $a$, and thus satisfies the condition? I'll leave it to you to formalize this with $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
This exercise is Exercise 12 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in this book.

My solution is here:

> 12(a)
> Let $a\in G_k$.
> Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(b)-f(c)|<\frac{1}{k}$ for all $b,c\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
> Let $d\in (a-\frac{\delta}{2},a+\frac{\delta}{2})$.
> Let $b,c\in (d-\frac{\delta}{2},d+\frac{\delta}{2})$.
> Then, $a-\frac{\delta}{2}<d<a+\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $d-\frac{\delta}{2}<b,c<d+\frac{\delta}{2}.$
> So, $a-\delta<d-\frac{\delta}{2}<b,c<d+\frac{\delta}{2}<a+\delta.$
> So, $b,c\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
> So, $|f(b)-f(c)|<\frac{1}{k}$.
> So, by the definition of $G_k$, $d\in G_k$.
> Therefore, $(a-\frac{\delta}{2},a+\frac{\delta}{2})\subset G_k.$
> So, $G_k$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

> 12(b)
> Let $a$ be a point at which $f$ is continuous.
> Let $k\in\{1,2,\dots\}.$
> Let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number such that $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2k}.$
> Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that if $|d-a|<\delta$, then $|f(d)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$
> Let $b,c\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.
> Then, $|f(b)-f(c)|\leq |f(b)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f(c)|<2\epsilon<\frac{1}{k}.$
> So, $a\in G_k$.
> $k$ was an arbitrary positive integer.
> So, $a\in\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty G_k.$
>
> Conversely, let $a\in\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty G_k.$
> Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
> Then, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon.$
> Since $a\in G_k$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(b)-f(c)|<\frac{1}{k}$ for all $b,c\in (a-\delta,a+\delta).$
> So, $|f(b)-f(a)|<\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$ for all $b\in (a-\delta,a+\delta).$ (Note that $a\in (a-\delta,a+\delta).$)
> So, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

> 12(c)
> Since $G_k$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for each positive integer $k$ by 12(a) above, $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty G_k$ is a Borel set by 2.25(c) on p.27 in the book.
> By 12(b) above, the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a Borel set.